# mutex and semaphore like in shell script

Tags: scripting, semaphore

## proc1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/proc1.signature.mutex
#do something for long time
sleep 100 
rm -rf /tmp/proc1.signature.mutex
```

## proc2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/proc2.signature.mutex
#do something for long time
sleep 100 
rm -rf /tmp/proc2.signature.mutex
```

## proc3.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/proc3.signature.mutex
#do something for long time
sleep 100 
rm -rf /tmp/proc3.signature.mutex
```

## core.sh

Now is there a way to wait for deleting /tmp/proc[?][*].signature.mutex all such file using loop or something 
and then continue further execution

How to achieve objective of core.sh

Comment: You can use `trap` so that the file `.mutex` is deleted on exit i.e: `trap 'rm -f /tmp/proc3.signature.mutex' EXIT`.

Comment: Have `core.sh` start the other scripts as background jobs, then use `wait` to wait for them to finish. No need for lock files (these  aren't mutexes).

Comment: Why not simply loop and check if proc file with index less than scripts current one exists in tmp directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mutex is a mutual exclusive lock. Your `procN.sh` scripts never test whether the mutex is held by another process before "locking".

If you let `core.sh` start the other scripts, it would be easy for it to wait for the completion of them:

```
#!/bin/sh

./proc1.sh &
./proc2.sh &
./proc3.sh &

wait

# other processing
```

This removes the need for the lock files altogether. If that's not possible, consider

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ -e "$HOME/locks/proc1.signature.mutex" ] ||
      [ -e "$HOME/locks/proc2.signature.mutex" ] ||
      [ -e "$HOME/locks/proc3.signature.mutex" ]
then
    echo 'waiting...'
    sleep 10
done

# other processing
```

To avoid leaving files behind by the `procN.sh` scripts if they die of unnatural causes, use a trap:

```
#!/bin/sh

lockfile="$HOME/locks/proc1.signature.mutex"

while [ -e "$lockfile" ]; do
    echo 'Can not get lock. Waiting...' >&2
    sleep 10
done
## alternatively:
# [ -e "$lockfile" ] && { echo 'something is wrong' >&2; exit 1; }

trap 'rm "$lockfile"; exit' EXIT INT TERM HUP
touch "$lockfile"

# etc.
# no need to rm the lock file at the end
```

Note that there is a space between the `-e "$lockfile"` test and the `touch` in which another process may lock the same file.

To avoid this, use a lock *directory* instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

lockdir="$HOME/locks/proc1.signature.mutex"

while ! mkdir "$lockdir"; do
    echo 'Can not get lock. Waiting...' >&2
    sleep 10
done

trap 'rmdir "$lockdir"; exit' EXIT INT TERM HUP

# etc.
# no need to rmdir the lock dir at the end
```

You may also use a symbolic link in a similar way.

Note that I've used a path under `$HOME` for the lock files/directories.  If using `/tmp`, any user could potentially lock your script out of action by simply creating the correct file/directory.

Comment: There probably should be warnings about `/tmp` usage as a local attacker could denial of service the file version with a broken symlink (and the directory version might use a `-d` check...)

Comment: @thrig Good point.

Comment: @thrig `-e` works on both files and directories, but you need `-h` to test existence of a symlink (it doesn't matter if it's broken)

Comment: IMHO checking if file with index less that current one should be sufficient. No need for 3 OR checks. Or have a single file which has PID of currently running script aka lockfile. That would add extra code for trapping exit or sigint and cleaning the lockfile and that should be enough - knowing that a file is used bu something should be enough of a sign for any proc script to avoid proceeding

Answer (score 0):

I wrote https://github.com/acbits/sema for this exact reason. I haven't been active on SE for a long time and just noticed this question. I have tested it only on Linux

Comment: Please explain how this is used.

Comment: @Scott My comment formatting didn't look good. Please look at answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Use https://github.com/acbits/sema to use semaphores in shell scripts.

```
 A.sh 
_____________________________________________
#!/bin/sh

echo A.sh started
sema -c S1
./B.sh &
echo A.sh more work
echo waiting for B.sh to finish
sema -w S1
echo B.sh finished execution
echo A.sh do more work
# cleanup semaphores
sema -d S1
_____________________________________________

B.sh
_____________________________________________
#!/bin/sh

echo Hello from B.sh
sleep 5
sema -r S1
echo Bye bye from B.sh
____________________________________________
```