# Does pid file work by assuming pid is not usable?

Tags: lock, pidfile

To use a pid file  for ensuring singleton running instance of a program, I thought that when a process finishes running the program, it should remove the pid file, until I know it doesn't when reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/7453411/156458:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp"
PIDFILE="$HOME/tmp/myprogram.pid"

if [ -e "${PIDFILE}" ] && (ps -u $(whoami) -opid= |
                           grep -P "^\s*$(cat ${PIDFILE})$" &> /dev/null); then
  echo "Already running."
  exit 99
fi

/path/to/myprogram > $HOME/tmp/myprogram.log &

echo $! > "${PIDFILE}"
chmod 644 "${PIDFILE}"
```

> Here's how it works: The script first checks to see if the PID file exists ("`[ -e "${PIDFILE}" ]`". If it does not, then it will start the program in the background, write its PID to a file ("`echo $! > "${PIDFILE}"`"), and exit. If the PID file instead does exist, then the script will check your own processes ("`ps -u $(whoami) -opid=`") and see if you're running one with the same PID ("`grep -P "^\s*$(cat ${PIDFILE})$"`"). If you're not, then it will start the program as before, overwrite the PID file with the new PID, and exit. I see no reason to modify the script

Does the above script assume that no pid is recycled?

Can it happen that  a  process finishes running the program, and its pid is reused by a new process running a different program? In such a case, the quoted script will falsely think that a process is running the program.

Thanks.

Comment: That piece of code is flawed in several ways, and not removing the PID file is just one of them. There are also race conditions, and that `ps | grep` looks _awkward_. Consider using a lock directory rather than a lock file. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401415/mutex-and-semaphore-like-in-shell-script

Comment: I originally thought that ensuring singleton instance of running a program is based on testing existing of a lock file, or someway entirely dependent on the lock files. When I read that reply and also another reply using `flock`, I found that both ways don't remove the lock files. Is removing a lock file not recommended in general? I also asked if we can tell if a process is running a program by only looking at the lock file https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478712/674

Comment: related on SO: [*Are PID-files still flawed when doing it 'right'?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906020/are-pid-files-still-flawed-when-doing-it-right)